# Giving a minecart momentum with a piston

Tags: minecraft-redstone, minecraft-java-edition

I am trying to setup a situation where I press a button and a minecart is pushed onto some powered track where it is then boosted up and giving a good speed.

This is what I tried (cross-section):

```
[P]M____

 ^ piston
   ^ minecart
    ^^^^ powered track
```

When I give power to the piston, the minecart gets shoved onto the powered track fine, however it just rests there. In order to get it boosted by the powered track, I have to manually touch it.

Is there a way to get the cart boosted automatically when it gets pushed onto the track?

Comment: What version of Minecraft are you using? 1.7, 1.8-pre, 1.8-pre2...

Comment: The 1.8-pre2 release

Comment: what about using a piston to push it onto an incline? Then gravity will move it onto the powered rail, and from there onto the powered rail where it can pick up speed normally?

Comment: @Tim I'm afraid I'll have to ask you to wait for 1.8 to come out then... unless you can reproduce this in 1.7... except we already do have a good answer!

Comment: @Raven: I tried that and it did work, however it required I build something at least 2 blocks high, and I was hoping to be able to do it all on the same level.

Comment: You could always build the incline one block lower instead of one block higher. You'd have a dip in the track, but if you'd keep everything else on the same level.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but you should also be able to accomplish this by pushing the minecart with a slime block in the latest snapshot. Slime blocks now give entities momentum when they push them.

Comment: Now I'm really confused. How was this a question about Minecraft 1.8 in 2011?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can be done without the piston at all.

If a cart is sitting on an inactive powered rail which begins receiving power, it will start moving as long as there is only one direction for it to go.  This occurs if…

- …the powered rail is sloped (you will go downhill), **or**
- …the cart's travel in one direction is blocked by a wall.

You can use this to start from the end of a track by placing a wall:

[image: Powered rail hill-climbing test]

Or in the middle of a track using a dip:

[image: MinecartStop]

(Images courtesy of the wiki's [page on powered rails](http://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Powered_Rail).)

Comment: "the cart's travel in one direction is blocked by a wall." - I didn't know about that. Thanks!

Comment: ARGH! typo in the list. downwill should be downhill. (sorry its my inner perfectionism)

Comment: @fireDude67 — Unhappiness is learning you missed a typo more than a month ago.  >.<

Comment: @Ben Unhappiness is learning you missed a typo when it jumps at you in [A0 format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_size)

Comment: @Tobias Kienzler — Touché… :-)